# Data not populating in select tag with AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Currently I have a select tag that I want to fill in via a AJAX call every time the user clicks on that particular select tag. To do this I'm doing the following:

View class:

```
<label class="control-labels ">Property</label>
     <select name="property" class="form-control select2 selectsearch" <?php echo (isset($read) ? $read:''); ?> required>
     </select>
```

Ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#property").click(function(){

    var post_url = 'listings/getonClick'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data : { "hid" : $(this).val() },
        success: function(response){
            $.each(response, function(value, key) {
                $("#property").append("<option id="+value.id+">"+value.name+"</option>");
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Controller Class:

```
function getonClick(){

    $modelList = $this->listings_model->getProperties();

    echo(json_encode($modelList));
}
```

Model Class:

```
 function getProperties(){
    $this->db->select("id,name");
    $this->db->from("crm_project_properties");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array() ;
 }
```

But after doing this, I cannot get any data in my select tag before or even after clicking on it

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also, filling the select after the user clicks on it sounds like it would be very annoying - the user would need to click it once for it to fill with options, then click it again to actually open the list.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so right now I have 3 select tags with around 30000 entries each which makes the page load very slow. So I need a way to minimize/remove this by making some AJAX call to maybe send it to another view or something. Also no errors in console

Comment: Having a dropdown with 30000 entries sounds like bad user experience anyway. Try using something like Select2 to dynamically load the options when the user types something

Comment: @brombeer okay so right now I have added select2 in my view class, but when I check the source, it still shows me 30000 lines worth of options inside a select

Comment: In that case you need to find a way to reduce that dataset. For example, can you split the list of 30k items in to separate categories, so you select some smaller dropdowns first to filter the dataset down. In any case, that's the real issue you need to solve. The above question is superfluous to the main issue you have, which is weight of data.

Comment: You need to dig a little deeper into the Select2 documentation, at least there's [Pagination](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#pagination) and you might also be able to only load results when the user typed X or more characters (not sure about that though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can ypu please try with .on("click")?
Its worked for me in past

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#property").on("click", '*:not(a)', function() {
       var post_url = 'listings/getonClick'
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: post_url,
           data : { "hid" : $(this).val() },
           success: function(response){
                $.each(response, function(value, key) {
                   $("#property").append("<option id="+value.id+">"+value.name+"</option>");
           })
         }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your Response to JSON Object first

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("#property").click(function(){

    var post_url = 'listings/getonClick'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data : { "hid" : $(this).val() },
        success: function(response){
            var responseText = JSON.parse(response);
            $.each(responseText , function(value, key) {
                $("#property").append("<option id="+value.id+">"+value.name+"</option>");
            })
        }
    });
});
```